# Is it possible to place 2 horizontal bars in a expandable list view?

Tags: android

As per my project requirement i need to place 2 horizontal bars in a expandable view. my question is that "is it possible to create a bar chart inside expandable list view?" If possible, Can any one please give me a suggestion how to put a bar chart in a expandable list with an example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a problem. You can back the data of an expandable list using an adapter:

```
YourAdapter implements ExpandableListAdapter
```

and connecting this adapter to your list:

```
yourList.setAdapter(YourAdapter)
```

Now, the ExpandableListAdapter Interface gives you some methods which you will have to implement. The most interesting regarding your question are:

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

and

```
getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Using those methods, Android basically asks you what those GroupViews and ChildViews (those are the ones that become visible when you click a groupView) should look like. You can return any View you like: Create one or you can load one from XML. When you're done, simply return it & Android will do the rest.

I Hope that helps you.